# cannot find namespace 'userAuthContext' in firebase login

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have the following code, that represents a file called `UserAuthContext.js` which is responsible for performing some operations during the firebase login and authentication process.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const userAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function signUp(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }
  function googleSignIn() {
    const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
      console.log("Auth", currentuser);
      setUser(currentuser);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <userAuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, logIn, signUp, logOut, googleSignIn }}
    >
      {children}
    </userAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserAuth() {
  return useContext(userAuthContext);
}
```

The code you saw above does not have any problems. What happens is that I need to transport this logic to a new project that was built with ReactJS + Vite (Typescript).

In my case, when I convert the extension from `.js` to `.ts`, the system claims that **"cannot find namespace userAuthContext"**:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState, ReactNode } from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";

import { auth } from "./firebaseConfig";

interface User {
  email: string | null;
  uid: string | null;
}

interface UserAuthContextType {
  user: User;
  logIn: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  signUp: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  logOut: () => Promise<void>;
  googleSignIn: () => Promise<void>;
}

const userAuthContext = createContext<UserAuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

interface UserAuthContextProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }: UserAuthContextProviderProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({ email: null, uid: null });

  function logIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  function googleSignIn() {
    const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      console.log("Auth", currentUser);
      if (currentUser) {
        setUser({ email: currentUser.email, uid: currentUser.uid });
      } else {
        setUser({ email: null, uid: null });
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <userAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, logIn, signUp, logOut, googleSignIn }}>
      {children}
    </userAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserAuth() {
  const context = useContext(userAuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useUserAuth must be used within a UserAuthContextProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?